# Performance differences between DEV and Production environment MYSQL server

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, phpmyadmin, eloquent

I'm building an app with Laravel 5.6 and VueJS requesting data from an API on the Laravel backend. In my DEV environment the queries take no time at all, but in the Production environment the response on the API takes 85.7 seconds opposed to 0.1 seconds in the DEV environment. Data is in both environments the same.

Using the follwoing commands in my Controller I was able to get the exact queries that run and I can test them one by one:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();

    // then my eloquent stuff
    $query = Sportevent::whereHas('photos')->with('photos');
    if($request->input('year')){
        $year = $request->input('year');
        $query = $query->where('date','like', $year.'%');
    }
    if($request->input('country')){
        $country = $request->input('country');
        $query = $query->where('country',$country);
     }
    $sportevents = $query->orderBy('date',"DESC")->paginate(10);

// then I display the queries:
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Here are the queries that are produced, not having selected a year or a country, incl performance in both environments with time:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// DEV: 0.0208 seconds | PROD: 73 seconds (had to use stopwatch)
// --------------------------------------------------------------
select count(*) as aggregate from `events` where exists 
   (select * from `photos` where `events`.`id` = `photos`.`eventID` 
   and `active` = 1)

// ------------------------------------------
// DEV: 0.025 seconds | PROD: 38.9721 seconds
// ------------------------------------------
select * from `events` where exists (select * from `photos` where
  `events`.`id` = `photos`.`eventID` and `active` = 1) 
   order by `date` desc limit 10 offset 0

// ------------------------------------------
// DEV: 0.0112 seconds | PROD: 0.0141 seconds
// ------------------------------------------
select * from `photos` where `active` = 1 and `photos`.`eventID` in 
    (11194, 11087, 10506, 10797, 9910, 10118, 10212, 9655, 10047, 10049)
```

The table events contains about 6000 entries and photos less than 50000 entries. If you need further details when it comes to table structure, let me know before down voting in the comments section :-)

On the production server are many other applications running with Laravel or Wordpress using databases on the same MySQL installation and none of them have similar issues.

Comment: dev and production db are different? If yes make sure indexes are present on production also.

Comment: It's all identical, there are no indexes apart from id as primary key defined on both tables.

Comment: May be your production server db engine configuration is much lower than your dev environment. Try to contact your hosting provider.

Comment: It's on a VPS... So I should be the master of my MySQL server

Comment: I just added an index on column `photos.eventID` that seems to do the trick. Fast as a rocket now... : 0.4 seconds for the API to respond

Comment: compare the `EXPLAIN {query}` output on both servers.

Comment: I don't get that EXPAIN command to work. But I think different server performances and adding an index are key here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the first two queries don't output much they have to go through the most data and therefore seem to be very memory and/or CPU intense queries.

It appears that my DEV environment has more power than my production environment and therefore I had this huge differences.

The solution at the end was simple: I added an INDEX of type INDEX to the column `photos.eventID` which would have been a good idea anyway.

This little change made my API respond in 0.4 seconds instead of 85.7

Comment: Tip for the future, EXPLAIN on both DEV and PROD would have clearly identified the missing index on PROD.

Comment: Thanks, I just need to figure out how to use that command :-)

Comment: @kevinkrause For initial research in Google search for 'mysql explain tutorial'  You will find it is truly EASY, precede your SELECT xxxxx  with EXPLAIN -  give it a shot, learn how to interpret the results, you will be amazed.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I don't use google anymore... I couldn't get around the documentation on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html , that's why I was asking for a quick pointer....

Comment: Alternatives to google include bing.com  or yahoo.com   -  wherever you search for things on the web will work.  This is the quickest pointer I know.  Have you tried what I suggested?  EXPLAIN before SELECT ..... for your introduction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :-) I'm already light-years past this problem and don't have the time at the moment to go back to it. However I will keep that in mind and will give that a try some other day....